# iOS In-App Purchases with dynamic content

Tags: ios

I want to built an app that it will support In-App Purchases.

In short, user will download the app (with some basic features), and he will have the ability to download extra layers (delivery content) with additional info (e.g. a recipe).

I want the content of this layer (the recipe) to be dynamic, and be downloadable (through web services) from a server.

What concerns me is, how i will secure the web services to be available, only to the users that have pay for the extra layer (using In-App Purchases)?

Is this functionality possible to be implemented in Google Play?

Answer (score 2):

There's two parts to this question.

- How do I ensure that people have to buy the in-app purchase before they can access the external data?
- How do I ensure that people can't access the external data from outside the app?

The first question is straightforward.  Just make sure you're implementing the in-app purchase APIs correctly, and that the request to your external server is inside one of those purchases, and you should be good.

The second question is fundamentally the same as any question about [securing web services](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7551/298754).  You just need to make sure that your app knows some secret which enables it to access your web service securely.